# get error when json_decode string from ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

I try send string to controller, the string is json format, when send to controller, i get error and can't decode my json string in that controller. I try to encode first in my controller, but still get error. And the error is

> "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given",
>   exception: "ErrorException",

here in my json string

```
"{ "data" : 
[{
"id": "TNI01",
 "jenis_bayar": "TUNAI",
"no_kartu": "kosong",
"nominal": "10000",
"seq": "1"
} , 
{
"id": "DEB01",
"jenis_bayar": "DEBIT BCA",
"no_kartu": "786382432432",
"nominal": "20000",
"seq": "2"
}]
}"
```

here the controller

```
public function ArrayPostToTablePembayaran(Request $request)
    {

       $data = json_decode($request->datajson, true);

       foreach ($data->data as $datas) 
       {
          $id         = $datas->id;
          $jenisbayar = $datas->jenis_bayar;
          $nokartu    = "";

          if($datas->no_kartu == "kosong")
          {
              $nokartu ="";
          }

          $nominal    = $datas->nominal;
          $seq        = $data->seq;
          $this->PosToTablePembayaran1($id , $jenisbayar , $nokartu , $nominal , $seq); 
       }
    }
```

and here the ajax script for parse json string to controller

```
function PembayaranKeDatabase1(arraystring)
            {
              $.ajax(
                  {
                      type    : "POST",
                      url     : "{{ url('/trx_bayar') }}",
                      data    : { datajson : JSON.parse(arraydata) } ,
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function(data){

                      },
                      error: function() {

                      }
                  });
            }
```

thanks before

Comment: So, what is unclear? You pass __array__ instead of string. `$request->datajson` is array already and you don't need to decode it.

Comment: So, I think passing json object to controller? if the string already to be array object, how to make that in foreach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in your code that you try to decode json **twice**: in client js code and on server.

Let's inspect what you do:

JS function `PembayaranKeDatabase1(arraystring)` has an argument of type **string**, I presume. I also presume that `arraystring` is a JSON-string. So, you **decode** JSON-string to object with

```
JSON.parse(arraydata)  
// btw shouldn't it be 
//JSON.parse(arraystring)
```

So, here you send some **plain object** to server, **not** json.

Next, on server you try to **decode** again. But you receive an array in `$request->datajson`, as json is already decoded on client-side.

So, you can choose between two options:

1. Remove `JSON.parse`:

   ```
   data    : { datajson : arraydata },
   ```

and use `json_decode` on server.

2. Remove `json_decode($request->datajson, true)` on server. Iterate over your data as

   ```
   // as $request->datajson is an array
   foreach ($request->datajson['data'] as $datas) {
       // use [] notation as you work with array, not object
       echo $datas['id'];
   }
   ```

Comment: if i choose first option, is the foreach script that I used before correct?

Comment: Correct, but option `true` in `json_decode` decodes data to __array__ and you'll need `[]` notation instead of `->`. If you still need __object__ and `->` - remove second argument of `json_decode`.

Comment: I thinks if i use json format, must decode in controller/server, but that already to be array format, thanks,